# Local DNS queries fail on server but work on clients

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

I have Ubuntu 14.04 server and I have Bind9 installed on it and configured. On client computers I have the DNS server address set to this server. `nslookup` for my custom DNS entries return the correct IP addresses. However, when querying the local DNS server on the Ubuntu server, it fails:

```
** server can't find intranet: NXDOMAIN
```

I checked that my server uses itself as the with `nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4`. I also tried querying with `nslookup intranet 10.0.2.1` on the server. The IP is the server's.

Why it doesn't work on the server itself?

Answer (score 0):

The resolver on your server needs to be configured to use itself as it's DNS server.  Check that `/etc/resolv.conf` has your IP address listed.  E.g.:-

```
nameserver 10.0.2.1
```

Also, NSS must be configured so that the resolver actually uses DNS for name resolution (as opposed to other systems).  Check that the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains a line similar to the following:-

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

This tells the resolver to first check the local database first (`/etc/hosts`) before trying DNS.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Same problem. The file gets overriden as soon as I save it.

Comment: Was the line originally there?  I've added some more info...

Comment: It's probably being overwritten by Network Manager.  There's an article on askubuntu that might help - http://askubuntu.com/questions/201603/how-do-i-edit-my-resolv-conf-file-to-fix-wrong-dns-problem

Comment: garethTheRed's comment (above) is likely the proper answer.  In Ubuntu, /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten at boot time.  You'll need to edit /etc/network/interfaces like the link (that garethTheRed provided) indicates.  You'll need a "dns-nameservers" line and a "dns-search" line.